# Change the color of an InkToolbar [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make the buttons of an UWP `InkToolbar` transparent, but changing the `background` property does not change the color of the control, is there another way to change the color of the buttons of the toolbar?

The XAML code I'm currently using is this:

```
<InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: How are you setting the background? If in code please show relevant snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the theme background brush in your `App.xaml` like this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InkToolbarButtonBackgroundThemeBrush">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you want more control, you can include the style that all the button styles are `BasedOn`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InkToolbarCommonButtonStyle"
           TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
                Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
                Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin"
                Value="-3" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```